# How to force Windows to have NO default printer?

Tags: windows, winapi

I am debugging a problem that occurs if the user has no **default** printer defined on his computer. I have not been able to recreate this situation on my PC.

I have tried to reproduce the problem by creating a placeholder printer, making it the default, then deleting it. Windows 10 insists on immediately making one of the remaining printers the default.

- I have gone into Windows Settings, Printers & Scanners, and UN-checked "Let Windows manage my default printer". Both for Standard user and Administrator.
- I have set the following Registry Key to 1 as described [here](https://windowsreport.com/default-printer-keeps-changing-windows-10/):
  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\LegacyDefaultPrinterMode = 1

Short of deleting all my printers, which I don't want to do, is there any way of fooling Windows into thinking there is no default printer?

Comment: Easiest to do this testing in a VM where you can remove all printers

Comment: Installing [Windows Sandbox](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Windows-Kernel-Internals/Windows-Sandbox/ba-p/301849) literally takes minutes.

Comment: Windows Sandbox doesn't seem to be available any more ?  I looked at this link but no solution from this .. Maybe our security people have this unavailable to us ..  https://www.guidingtech.com/fix-windows-10-sandbox-mode-missing-issue/